# AVSpeechUtterance - Swift - initializing with a phrase

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

So I'm just trying to use the AVSpeechSynthesizer with Swift.  I cannot figure out how to set the phrase for the AVSpeechUtterance.

```
@IBAction func buttonSpeakClicked(sender:UIButton)
    {
        var mySpeechSynthesizer:AVSpeechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        var myString:String = "This is the phrase to say"
        var mySpeechUtterance:AVSpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:myString)

        println("\(mySpeechUtterance.speechString)")
        println("My string - \(myString)")

        mySpeechSynthesizer .speakUtterance(mySpeechUtterance)
    }
```

First println - Nil

Second println - This is the phrase to say

Documentation says init(string string: String!), but I can't figure out where to put it

Comment: Not necessary to add the type annotations to your vars. I.e. you can drop `:AVSpeechSynthesizer`, `:String`, `:AVSpeedUtterance`...

Comment: So what exactly happened when you tried to run this? i am playing around with a single view app that has a button which on clicking invokes AVSpeechUtterance.speakUtterance, when clicking that button on UI, it just throws an exception. did you experience the same thing as well? I import of the AvFoundation module, in my code, so the code does not throw any errors until run-time.

Comment: I don't remember what beta version I was using when I originally posted this.  I was not getting any errors, but the speechUtterance could not be set on the iOS8 simulator.  Now that it is in beta 6, the same code produces the correct println's, the speechUtterance is being set properly.  But it doesn't actually speak on the simulator (iPhone 5S, iOS8).  It gives an error "Speech initialization error: 2147483665"  It does work properly on my iphone 4S running the current beta of iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is fine, speech string is set correctly. However issue is that AVSpeechUtterance is not working as expected on iOS 8 Beta. I suggest file a bug report [here](https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem).

The code works fine on iOS 7.1 device and simulator.

Comment: Yeah, looks a bit freaky. If you construct an AVSpeechUtterance with a string of any kind, as far as I can see, you get `nil` back. If you construct it with no parameters, it works fine, and you get an object, but then of course you can't set the speech string, as the speechString property is readonly.

Comment: Bug report filed - 17498112

Comment: OMG! I thought I was going crazy that I could not get this to work on 8. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, its a bug. As of iOS8 GM, it seems the first attempt to get AVSpeechSynthesizer to speak an AVSpeechUtterance will result in silence.

My workaround is to make AVSpeechSynthesizer speak a single-character utterance immediately after it is initialized.  This will be silent, and afterwards your AVSpeechSynthesizer will work as normal.

In Objective-C:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *bugWorkaroundUtterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@" "];
bugWorkaroundUtterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate;
[self.speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:bugWorkaroundUtterance];
```

Comment: Great! It works well on real device. (Xcode 6.0.1 , iOS 8.0.2, iPhone 5) But the simulator didn't work still. thx

Comment: For me, this bug is still occurring in iOS 8.0.2 on an iPhone 4S.  The above workaround _does work_, but for me _only_ if I matched the utterance.rate and utterance.voice. I'm specifying an utterance.rate = 0.2 * AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate on my actual utterance, and I had to do that on the bugWorkaroundUtterance _as well_ in order for this workaround to work. I'm playing the @" " workaround utterance in viewDidLoad. Now when playing back TTS in the UI, it works the first time around, even in iOS 8.0.2. Hope this extra info helps some of you that may still be struggling with this. :-)

Comment: 8.1 SDK, Xcode 6.1... Still an issue in the simulator on any device. Works fine with the 7.1 SDK.

Comment: XCode 6.2 beta 2 with WatchKit did resolve this issue: simulator works again.