# AVSpeechSynthesizer voices on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, avspeechsynthesizer

Is anyone else unable to use the AVSpeechSynthesizer with a voice other than "en-US"? The array that gets returned when I call `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices` still returns the complete list that can be seen in iOS 7, but none of them actually work.

I tried looking through the known issues on the iOS 8 release notes, but didn't see anything about this. Hopefully this is something that will be fixed in the full version, as I have a couple apps that make use of multiple voices.

Comment: Same issue here. Hoping it's a beta bug.

Comment: Filed Radar #18022866

Comment: Either that or maybe they left the different voices out to reduce the size of the beta downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to have been fixed in iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is a bug in iOS8, even for GM. 
I was playing with this project: https://github.com/mattt/AVSpeechSynthesizer-Example

My findings are:

1) iOS 8 did not speak in any simulator (XCode 6GM, XCode 6.1b2). It did speak only on real device.

2 ) iOS 8 did speak in language of phone (Russian in my case) and English (en-US). When i did change Language of a phone to german, i can hear German and English TTS. Adding German as one of languages in preffered language list did not help, you should set language as phone language. For unknow reasons Russian did work even if it was not phone language, but not same for German - it was working only if it was set as a phone language. Maybe real location matters (I am in Russia). For sure: iOS8 did "optimize" TTS engines some way, so not all of them are ok to use.

3) some folks noticed another bug in iOS 8: first attempt to use AVSpeechSynthesizer produces silence. See workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472766/avspeechutterance-swift-initializing-with-a-phrase/25839466#25839466).